# How to retrieve currently open documents in LibreOffice (calc, writer, etc.)

Tags: macros, libreoffice, python3, document-automation

I need to read / retrieve / get / enumerate currently open documents in any LibreOffice app (Writer, Calc, Present, Draw), on linux.

What I tried:

- Searching the command line history is not helpful: Files can be opened/closed in LO via menus.
- The Recent Document list shows only past docs).
- using UNO-API, I was able to read only current document.
  I couln't find a command to enumerate / list all active documents.

This UNO python program just prints the **active** document's path. ~~But I didn't find a way to read all active documents~~.

```
#!/opt/libreoffice6.4/program/python
import unohelper
import os
import uno
localContext = uno.getComponentContext()        # get the uno component context from the PyUNO runtime
resolver = localContext.ServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.bridge.UnoUrlResolver", localContext )
ctx = resolver.resolve( "uno:socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext" )     # connect to the running office
smgr = ctx.ServiceManager
desktop = smgr.createInstanceWithContext( "com.sun.star.frame.Desktop",ctx)
model = desktop.getCurrentComponent()
print(model.URL)
```

### Solution:

Thanks to Jim K's answer (My version here is slightly more pythonic) :

```
components = desktop.getComponents()
docs = oComponents.createEnumeration()
for doc in docs:
    location = doc.Location
    title = doc.Title
```

Comment: LibreOffice naming is a pain in the butt, especially when coming from VBA naming bg:  "components" should've been "documents", and all the namespace has a huge overhead.

Comment: In LibreOffice, not all components are documents, for example, the Basic IDE. Also, there may be some older versions where `for doc in docs` fails. If you want to take shortcuts like that, then be sure to test the versions of LibreOffice and Python that the code needs to be compatible with.

Comment: As far as I can see, in Basic one has to access `desktop` using the name `StarDesktop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [XDesktop.getComponents()](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/frame/XDesktop.html#getComponents).

```
DOCTYPE_WRITER = 'writer'
DOCTYPE_CALC = 'calc'

def getOpenDocs(self, doctype='any'):
    """Returns currently open documents of type doctype."""
    doclist = []
    oComponents = self.desktop.getComponents()
    oDocs = oComponents.createEnumeration()
    while oDocs.hasMoreElements():
        oDoc = oDocs.nextElement()
        if oDoc.supportsService("com.sun.star.text.TextDocument"):
            if doctype in ['any', self.DOCTYPE_WRITER]:
                doclist.append(oDoc)
        elif oDoc.supportsService("com.sun.star.sheet.SpreadsheetDocument"):
            if doctype in ['any', self.DOCTYPE_CALC]:
                doclist.append(oDoc)
    return doclist
```

Comment: As far as I can see, in Basic one has to access `self.desktop` using the name `StarDesktop`.